# Place div border infront of containing text (with fixed display)

Tags: html, css, border

This is what I have:

[image]

However, I want the shadow below the text to not appear on top of the border. I can get this effect when my 'position' of the heading is set to anything other than "absolute" or "fixed", but I lose flexiblity in animation... which is what I want to do later.

here is my code:

```
.feature {
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/The_Last_of_Us_Concept_Art_Crows_JS-01.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: solid 5px #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #333;
}

.feature h1 {
position: fixed;
font-size: 120px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left: 50px;
font-family: "oswald", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
transition: margin 0.5s;
}

#moral {
margin-top: 160px;
} 

#studios {
margin-top: 160px;
margin-left: 400px;
}
```

also... my vertical align text-bottom isn't working...that is why I use the top margin.. can anyone tell me why?

Arman

Comment: I think you can't make this effect without making the border line a independent element. Implement it as an <hr/> and set it z-index greater than the text.

Comment: did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Posted. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't make this effect without making the border line a independent element. 
Implement it as an `<hr/>` and set it z-index greater than the text.